# Using Button instead of Submit

Tags: html, input, tags, submit

I happend to be using a rel attribute that can not be validated ("Attribute rel not allowed on element input at this point.") correctly because the Submit buttons can't support them. Is using a  tag the right solution for this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: You will either need to show your code or clarify the question further.  What are you using the rel attribute for?

Comment: You need to show code, and specifically the doctype you are validating against.

Answer (score 1):

You should put all extra information in a "data" tag and apply processing via javascript.